# Angularjs - How to group by rows with the same value in a specific column into one cell?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have these columns:

```
Column1     Column2      Column3
   1           a            x
   1           b            y
   2           c            z
```

I want the result to be:

```
Column1     Column2      Column3
   1           a            x
               b            y
   2           c            z
```

where row 1 and row 2 is in the same cell.

How can I achieve this with Angularjs? I've read some others uses external dependencies. Can I achieve this without using external dependencies?

Here is my sample code (run the snippet):

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col1</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col2</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in obj">

                <td> {{ item.col1 }} </td>
                <td> {{ item.col2 }} </td>
                <td> {{ item.col3 }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.obj = [{ col1: 1, col2: "a", col3: "x" }, { col1: 1, col2: "b", col3: "y" }, { col1: 2, col2: "c", col3: "z" }];
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this might could help you <td> {{ item.col1 !== obj[$index -1].col1 ? item.col1 : '' }} </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I mention on the comment.

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col1</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col2</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in obj">
                <td> {{ item.col1 !== obj[$index -1].col1 ? item.col1 : '' }} </td>
                <td> {{ item.col2 }} </td>
                <td> {{ item.col3 }} </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.obj = [{ col1: 1, col2: "a", col3: "x" }, { col1: 1, col2: "b", col3: "y" }, { col1: 2, col2: "c", col3: "z" }];
    });
</script>
```

the idea to tricky the output with ternary operator

```
condition ? true : false
```

Comment: Isn't this heavy on the client side if you put conditions in the view?

Comment: @JPDolocanog what do you mean?. do you want it to be in server side? angular is Javascript where it serve in the browser which is mean it is also in client side.

Comment: @mtmma what I mean is that, will it affect the memory consumption on the process of that conditions? Let's assume that I have 1000 data in my db that i need to show. Will the conditional statement affect the process in showing the data?

Comment: i don't think so it's gonna affect the memory consumption comparing by putting the solution in the controller. by go through each record of the object and do conditional statement.

Comment: Because of what I know, placing too much logic on the view is a bad practice. And using logic on directives could cause some unforeseen issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky but try this.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col1</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col2</th>
            <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in obj | unique: 'col1'">
        <tr ng-repeat="item in obj  | filterdataacckeyword:'col1':item.col1">
            <td> <span ng-if="$index == 0"> {{ item.col1 }} </span> </td>
            <td> {{ item.col2 }} </td>
            <td> {{ item.col3 }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then copy this filter to your code

```
app.filter('filterdataacckeyword', [function () {
      return function (input, keyinclude, search) {
          input = input || [];
          var out = [];
          if(search!=undefined) {
               input.forEach(function (item) {
                   var flag = false;
                   keyinclude.split(',').forEach(function(key) {
                       if (!(typeof yourVariable === 'object') && item[key]!=null && item[key]!="." && item[key]!="" &&
                           item[key].toLowerCase() == search.toLowerCase()) {
                           if(!flag) {
                               out.push(item);
                               flag=true;
                           }
                       }
                   });
               });
           }
           else {
               out = input;
           }
           return out;
       };
   }]);
```

P.S. I purposely placed the first `ng-repeat` on the tbody. It will loop the unique col1 while the inner tr will loop the cols with same col1